# Filter wildcards not behaving the same way or as intended

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I am attempting to get the following filter statement to work correctly, however, it does not. exportedLibaries contains the relative path to the files from where make it being executed from (i.e. `export/*/*/*/filename`)

```
dev := $(filter HelloWorld%, $(exportedLibraries))
```

I use a similar filter for my unit tests and it works wonderfully (with the relative path being the same):

```
unitTests := $(filter %_Test, $(exportedUnitTests))
```

This however works...

```
dev := $(filter $(wildcard export/**/**/**/HelloWorld*), $(exportedLibraries))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I get your explanation right, the first filter won't work because in $(exportedLibraries) the names contain the path starting with `export/` but your pattern is without a prefixed path (`HelloWorld%`).

Comment: In the second filter, $(exportedUnitTests) also contain the path starting with export

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the first argument of $filter, which is `HelloWorld%` (no path) in the non-working case and `export/whatever/nother/onemore/HelloWorldxyz` in the other case.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Is there a way so I don't have to provide the entire path? I've attempted to do `%HelloWorld%`, but to no avail.

Comment: make can't process more than one `%` as wildcard per pattern. Every `%` after the first one is taken verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(notdir) is what you want in this case:

```
exportedLibraries := export/foo/helloworld.lib export/bar/HelloWorld.lib export/baz/HelloWorldTwo.lib

dev := $(foreach lib,$(exportedLibraries),$(if $(filter HelloWorld%,$(notdir $(lib))),$(lib)))

$(info $(dev))
```

You could `$(strip)` the result of the `$(foreach)` to get rid of surplus spaces in the result.